# Can not add function to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I don't know when the problem begin. I find that when i create a new function to mongodb, and then run it like this:

`db.loadServerScripts();
testFun('xxx');`

Two errors will occur:

`SyntaxError: missing } after property list src/mongo/shell/db.js:1038`


`ReferenceError: testFun is not defined (shell):1`

But the old functions work fine. And when I delete one old function, and recreate it without anything changed, it also results in the same error above.

The version of mongodb I used is `2.6.10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to this question. The error was cased by some other function. The error message puzzled me , I used to think that it must be an error from the mongo itself. I delete some mongo function written by me, and then the error was missing. Now I can run `testFun` successfully.